# Running validation on one form for multiple non-nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have one form which collects data for two completely unrelated models. The models are not nested. I'd like to know the best way to perform the validation and display combined error messages.

I'm assuming I need a view something like this, but I'm not sure how to combine the error messages and display them all at once.

```
<%= form_for @first_model do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

    <%= f.label :instructions %>
    <%= f.text_area :instructions %>

    <%= fields_for @second_model do |ff| %>
        <%= ff.label :quantity %>
        <%= ff.text_field :quantity %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

`fields_for` in your view is wrong. This would have been if `second_model` were nested into `first_model`.

I believe that you have to change your approach here. My suggestion is that you should define a new `class` as a tableless model that unifies the attributes of both of your models. Then you should develop your view on this new model.

BTW, `active_attr` (find it [here](https://github.com/cgriego/active_attr)) gem does a fantastic job to let you define such models.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If I do this, where should I define my validation rules? It would make sense to move the validation out of the current models and into the tableless model, but that kind of feels dirty.. how would you go about this?

Comment: @DerekHarrington The tableless model need to have validations yes. But your persistent models have to have validations too. They are not always the same. But both have to have validations. I do not consider this dirty. The tableless model is for form validation. The persistent models are for business / domain validation. The latter exist irrespective of the form. You may change your form / UI but still latter validations will remain the same. This is the principle of decoupling UI from domain/business logic. This is how I would do it, and I have done in the past.